# How do I install Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-10

The obvious downloading and running of the installer doesn't work.  It says it completes, whereupon it requires a reboot.  When the machine comes back up post-reboot, Internet Explorer 9 is active and 10 is nowhere to be found!

Doesn't matter if run as admin or not.  Tried using the MS SURT utility, no change.  The machine has Intel HD Graphics 3000.  The system is Windows 7 x64.

Ideas?

Comment: Does your MSI write verbose logs to C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp? Is there any logs in the System event list under MSIinstaller that may give a clue to a failed installation?

Comment: in C:\Windows there is a IE10Main.log, upload this log to pastebin and post a link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the 3000 is supposedly technically able to run IE10, the driver we have is not.  Waiting on an updated video driver (as one is currently not available).